# How to implement the alias for function name in serverless.yml for aws lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I want to add alias name for AWS Lambda function name in serverless.yml file. Like;

```
functions:
  pushContent:
    handler: src/function/pushContent/index.handler
    role: pushContentRole
    **aliasName: pushContentAlias**
```

Is it possible to do it ? I could not find how to do it. Thanks

Comment: What do you want to use the alias for? Why don't you just use that as your function name?